# anonymous User broken

Tags: 7, users, entities, database

I just migrated the site from sqlite to Postgres, using the drush portabledb-import module

I'm getting a error page only when no user is logged in to the site.

I can get logged in using the login-link generated running

`drush user-login`

and everything works great, all the content is there and accessible, views all work, etc...
however log out and I get this message at the home page again

**The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.**

and The watchdog-show reports this

 `ID         :  8
 Date       :  12/Mar 13:07
 Type       :  php
 Severity   :  error
 Message    :  PDOException: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "not yet assigned"
               LINE 4: WHERE  (base.uid IN  ('not yet assigned'))
                                             ^: SELECT base.uid AS uid, base.name AS name, base.pass AS pass, base.mail AS mail, base.theme AS theme, base.signature AS signature, base.signature_format AS signature_format, base.created AS created, base.access AS access, base.login AS login, base.status AS status, base.timezone AS timezone, base.language AS language, base.picture AS picture, base.init AS init, base.data AS data, base.uuid AS uuid
               FROM
               {users} base
               WHERE  (base.uid IN  (:db_condition_placeholder_0)) ; Array
               (
                   [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => not yet assigned
               )
                in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 191 of/usr/local/www/main/includes/entity.inc).`

I've checked the DB and the 0 uid looks fine
but just in case I followed the "Restore the anonymous (user ID 0) user record docs located here
https://drupal.org/node/1029506

any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something in the code is doing that query with the value "not yet assigned" in place of the user id. If you can find that text string, you'll find the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can migrate like that.  I am pretty sure the database creation during installation process is different if you're using postgres.